# How do I enable a stick pointing device in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, touchpad, trackpoint

How do I enable/disable a stick pointing device in Ubuntu (9.10)? How can I configure clicking and scrolling with the stick pointer? (I can't click with the stick and scroll the page.)

Comment: More details please. What version of Ubuntu, what hardware? What did you try, what happened?

Comment: It's a pointing stick, not a sticking point. That might be a sticking point for readers of your pointing stick question.

Comment: @mmyers good point, edits stuck.

Comment: I agree with sleske--much more information is needed, like exactly what device.

Answer (score 3):

for gui solution

```
$ sudo apt-get install gpointing-device-settings
$ gpointing-device-settings
```

for command line

```
$ xinput list
# find your device name there
$ xinput list-props "PointingStick" # the name can be different
# this will list available settings for that pointing stick
$ xinput set-*-prop "PointingStick" ...
# to set a property, see man page for more how to set properties

an example how to set it for thinkpad
$ xinput set-int-prop '"TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint"' "Evdev Wheel Emulation" 8 1
$ xinput set-int-prop '"TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint"' "Evdev Wheel Emulation Button" 8 2
$ xinput set-int-prop '"TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint"' "Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout" 8 200

to disable device
$ xinput set-int-prop "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint" "Device Enabled" 8 0
to enable 
$ xinput set-int-prop "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint" "Device Enabled" 8 1
```

For more information see [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Input#Input%20Configuration%20with%20HAL) and [this](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_configure_the_TrackPoint).

Comment: How to disable point stick ?

Comment: something like `xinput set-int-prop "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint" "Device Enabled" 8 0`

Comment: @SjB: did it help or not?

Comment: No i can't disable it

Comment: @SjB so does it show an error message or just doesn't work? What exactly did you try? (just in case: Did you adjust the name of the pointing device?)